# How to access nested class in Drools

Tags: scala, drools

I am beginner in Drools.
I have this model in scala :

```
case class OuterClass (int parentValue ) {
   lazy val childs: Seq[InnerClass] = getChilds()

   case class InnerClass (int childValue ) {
   }
}
```

I need to create a Drools rule that checks parents with parentValue  = 1, and having at least one child with childValue = 2

I created this rule:

```
dialect "mvel"
import com.models.OuterClass
rule "1"
when
 $parent: OuterClass($pv: parentValue, $c: childs, $pv == 1)
 $parent.InnerClass($cv: childValue, $cv == 2) from $c
then
 "do something"
end
```

But I get following error: "Unable to resolve ObjectType '$parent.InnerClass'"

How can I access nested class in Drools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it!

The rule you are looking for is something like this:

```
rule "1"
when
  $parent: OuterClass($pv: parentValue == 1)
  $inner: InnerClass($cv: childValue == 2) from $parent.childs
then
  "do something"
end
```

As you can see, the relation between the parent and the child is stated in the right side of the `from`.

The problem with this rule is that is going to be executed as many times as children with a value == 2 an `OuterClass` object has. If you just want to check for the presence of **at least one** child with value ==2, then you can try something like this:

```
rule "1"
when
  $parent: OuterClass($pv: parentValue == 1)
  exists( InnerClass(childValue == 2)) from $parent.childs
then
  "do something"
end
```

Note that in this case, you can't bind variables to the second pattern because you don't know which one it will be.

If you need to get information about the `InnerClass` object/s matching the pattern, but you still want to get the rule executed only once, a strategy could be to collect all the `InnerClass` objects in a collection:

```
rule "1"
when
  $parent: OuterClass($pv: parentValue == 1)
  $list: List(size > 0) from collect( 
    InnerClass(childValue == 2) from $parent.childs
  )
then
  "do something"
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
When I try to your solution, I get the error : "Unable to resolve objectType InnerClass". I cannot directly instantiate InnerClass without having an instance of type OuterClass, and I cannot add InnerClass to my import statement as well : import com.models.OuterClass.InnerClass does not work.

Comment: hmmm... I'm not familiar with Scala, but I would recommend you to find a way to import that class in the DRL.

Comment: I changed my model to put InnerClass as separate class and it works now. Thanks